# How to make a Dynamic FlowControlPanel visible in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a dynamic `flowcontrolPanel` and make it visible after adding controls to it. However the problem now is, the controls are added successfully but the panel is not visible on the screen. The below piece of code is a sample which I have tried form my side:

```cs
List<object> lstChild = lstFromChild;
//creating an instance for the flowlayoutpanel         
FlowLayoutPanel objflowParent = new FlowLayoutPanel(); 
objflowParent.Name = "flowLayoutParent";
objflowParent.Location = new Point(380,155);
objflowParent.Size = new Size(800, 800);
objflowParent.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
objflowParent.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
objflowParent.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
objflowParent.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
objflowParent.Size = new Size(300, 30);
objflowParent.SuspendLayout();
//Adding Controls to the flowlayoutpanel
foreach (Control item in lstChild)
{
    objflowParent.Controls.Add(item);                   
}
objflowParent.ResumeLayout(false);
//Tried to hide a datagrid available in the screen to check if it is hiding the panel
dgMainGrid.Hide();
this.Show();
```

Note: `lstChild` is the list carried form another form with controls loaded in it.

Comment: You never added the `objflowParent` to whatever `this` is. You probably need: `this.Controls.Add(objflowParent);`

Comment: You solved my issue.Thank you so much :)